# How can I invert the color of a selected/using window in Window 10

Tags: windows-10, dark-mode, mendeley

I want to invert a pdf window (Mendeley Viewer) for dark mode reading. The current `color filter` or `magnifier` in the setting will invert the whole screen. Are there any application or method that I can use to invert only a selected/using window instead of the whole screen?

In Ubuntu, I can easily do this by `super + I`. It will be strange if Window doesn't support something like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the program https://windowtop.info. Its free version allows users to invert only a selected/using window instead of the whole screen

Demo:

[image]

Comment: awesome, thank u sir

Comment: this doesn't work on multiple monitor, btw.